# How to exclude a hidden folder from being deleted

Tags: bash, gnu-findutils

The following command will remove all files and folders in the current directory, except for those mentioned.

```
find . -mindepth 1 ! -path '*testResults*' ! -path '*artifacts*' ! -path '*node_modules*' -exec rm -r {} + 2>/dev/null
```

My question is: how to also exclude the .git hidden folder from getting deleted?

Comment: I think you would need to use `-path` and `-prune`... see if https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97558/find-combining-path-and-prune-to-exclude-files-and-directories helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `! -name '.git'`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 ! -path '*testResults*' ... ! -name '.git' ...
```

The fact that you use `! -path` but don't know about `! -name` shows that you just pick some random stuff from the internet instead of looking at the right place of information: The man page! So just go ahead and type:

```
man find
```

Comment: The fact that you assume stuff is cute. I did read parts of https://ss64.com/bash/find.html but it was just too exhaustive and I missed stuff. Horray for people helping out?

Comment: Looks like my assumption was correct. And no, the man page of the find command is *not* too exhaustive. `find` just has more than 3 options. On the other hand I do hope my assumption that you downvoted the answer I gave you is wrong because this is something that is personally so poor that I haven't seen it in 6 years stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I downvoted your answer because albeit it being correct, your attitude reeks. Grow some manners.

Comment: What attitude? The attitude to point you to the `find` man page? Man! As a dev-ops, which you claim to be on your profile, you'll need to look often at the man page of the find command since it has many options and you won't be able to keep them all in in mind. While `-name` is something I know out of my head, I look at the man page at least once a week. Actually it is pretty  simple structured: `Options, Expressions, Filters, Actions` where one often needs to lookup something from `Filters and Actions`. Short to remember: Being able to read the `find` man page is *essential*.